# IntelliJ code completition "template"

Tags: intellij-idea

When I invoke code completion like this :

[image]

And press enter I am left with :

```
String.valueOf()
```

But I would like for IntelliJ to insert the "template" of the selected option for the completion. From the example screenshot it would be :

```
String.valueOf(data, offset, count)
```

End allow me to move with the tab between data, offset and count. Can it be done? Btw, I am on OSX 10.5+ shortcuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in Windows will give an overlay, stating the same info you saw before pressing enter. <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> with OS X keybindings. It's called *parameter info*.

Not tabbable, but at least you get the possible signatures while writing.

[image: intellij parameter info]